# Unable to install couchbase in python on macOs

Tags: couchbase, python-3.8

I am trying to install couchbase on my macOS. I am using `pip3 install couchbase` to install it.
And I am getting error as

```
    `note: '__uint128_t' declared here
      /Library/Developer/C
    ommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:76:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
      typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_useconds_t;    /* [???] microseconds */
              ^
      note: '__uint128_t' declared here
      In file included from src/bucket.c:18:
      In file included from src/pycbc.h:45:
      In file included from src/python_wrappers.h:20:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:43:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
      typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_wctype_t;
              ^
      note: '__uint128_t' declared here
      In file included from src/bucket.c:18:
      In file included from src/pycbc.h:45:
      In file included from src/python_wrappers.h:20:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:75:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_va_list.h:31:
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/machine/types.h:37:2: error: architecture not supported
      #error architecture not supported
       ^
      fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
      20 errors generated.
      /private/tmp/pip-install-46t38raq/couchbase_25d29b67ce814e2badeb9f2deaba5d2c/cbuild_config.py:271: UserWarning: Adding /usr/local to lib search path for OS X
        warnings.warn('Adding /usr/local to lib search path for OS X')
      error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------

   
   ERROR: Failed building wheel for couchbase Failed to build couchbase
   ERROR: Could not build wheels for couchbase which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

I also tried `pip3 install --no-use-pep517 couchbase` then also I am getting `could not build a wheel for couchbase`
I have upgraded my pip to the latest. I have python3.8. I also installed pep517.

Comment: I installed anaconda and reinstalled using ```pip3 install couchbase``` it worked. It might have been the issue with my python setup